# Render CAShapeLayers on CAMetalLayer

Tags: ios, swift, metal, cashapelayer, cametallayer

I am trying to draw a few hundred static paths to an image as fast as possible. So far the fastest solution I've come up with is using `CAShapeLayers`:

```
let layer = CALayer()

let f = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)
let cgColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

var lines: [CGPath] // populated with several hundred paths, some with hundreds of points

let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    
for path in lines {
    let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    pathLayer.path = path
    pathLayer.strokeColor = cgColor
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    pathLayer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously
    layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
layer.render(in: ctx!)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//time: 0.05170309543609619
print("time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)")
```

Drawing the lines takes about 0.001 a second, producing an image is what is taking most the time. Also, the above method is about the same speed or perhaps a bit faster than using  `CARenderer`. So I've tried using a `CAMetalLayer` and generating an image with `Metal` instead of `CoreGraphics`.

I can verify that the lines are drawn to the layer, either by adding the layer to a view or rendering it with the above method, but I get a blank image out using `CAMetalLayer`'s `mtlTexture`.

```
let layer = CAMetalLayer()
let f = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)
shapeLayer.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
shapeLayer.bounds = f
shapeLayer.frame = f
shapeLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
shapeLayer.framebufferOnly = false

for path in lines {
    let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    pathLayer.path = path
    pathLayer.strokeColor = cgColor
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    pathLayer.drawsAsynchronously = drawsAsynchronously
    layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
}

let outputImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: layer.nextDrawable()!.texture)
```

The resulting mage is blank:
[image]

I tried using a `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` but the image is blank as well:

```
public func render(caLayer: CAMetalLayer) -> UIImage? {
    
    let passDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    let tex = caLayer.nextDrawable()?.texture
    
    passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = tex
    passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 0.5, 1, 0.05);
    passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear;
    passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store;

    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
          let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue(),
          let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return nil }
            
    let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: passDescriptor)
    renderCommandEncoder?.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()
    
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: tex!)!
    let img = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    
    return img
    
}
```

Comment: Since this is similar to your other question... it's difficult to help with abstracts. Are you trying to speed up drawing operations? Speed up converting path drawing to a `UIImage`? Are you trying to animate something?

Comment: Yes, it is a different approach using `CAMetalLayer`. I'm trying to speed up converting a paths to a `UIImage` since drawing the paths is fast but getting an image is slow. Static image.

Comment: *"//time: 0.05170309543609619"* ... Are you hoping to render hundreds of paths to a 1024x1024 `UIImage` in *less than **5/100ths** of a second*?

Comment: Yes. 1024 really is not a large image and a few hundred paths isn't really a lot of paths. For my Metal paint engine, I render 16K images at 30+ fps. Seems like it should be possible to generate a 1K image with a few hundred paths in about 0.005 seconds since it is certainly possible to animate a few hundred paths rendered to the screen at considerably higher resolution and at 30+ fps.

Comment: To put it another way, it is certainly faster to get an image from Metal than it is with CoreGraphics. It is 0.05 is with CoreGraphics, and nearly all that time is getting the image.

Comment: Just timed a 1024x1024px `UIImage` from `MTLTexture` took 0.000059 seconds, so if the `CAShapeLayers` are rendered to the `MTLTexture` backed `CAMetalLayer`, it should be very fast.

Comment: I mean, in none of the examples you are actually drawing anything to a Metal texture. You are just converting an empty metal texture to an image. Adding shape layer as a sublayer to `CAMetalLayer` is not gonna magically draw into the texture.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the whole point of `CAMetalLayer`. I thought that since `CALayers` are drawn with the GPU they could be accessed with a `MTLTexture` without having to use the CPU. What is the point of `CAMetalLayer` then? Anyhow; the 0.000059 second figure is timed using a `MTLTexture` filled with pixels and not an empty image.

Comment: I meant the second snippet where you add sublayers to the metal layer. The compositor does not composite sublayers into your metal layer. The purpose of metal layer is to give you the MTLTexture that you can render into and that compositor can then combine into an image on screen. The compositor is not going to write back to the metal layer MTLTexture the stuff it composited, because that makes exactly zero sense.

Comment: Like I said, I misunderstood the point of `CAMetalLayer`. I found very little documentation on it, very few examples and thought it was worth a shot. Isn't the whole point of SO to ask questions when you don't know the answer?

Comment: Most of the sample projects here use `CAMetalLayer`. https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/ And I think I am kind of answering your question. I'm just saying that it's not how it works.

Comment: I meant very few examples with `CAShapeLayers` using `CAMetalLayer`. I guess I just don't really appreciate your belittling tone.